# What is the best way to cache static html that contains dynamic content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, russian-doll-caching

I am using haml and Russian doll caching in rails. My goal is to cache as much static html as possible and only render dynamic content. However, I often have a large section of uncached html because there is a small bit of dynamic code in the middle.

Suppose I have this view containing 2 partials:

**show.html.haml**

```
= render 'message'
```

**_container.html.haml**

```
.nested
  .divs
    = render 'dynamic'
```

**_dynamic.html.haml**

```
= complex_stuff
.something
  = more_complex_stuff
```

I cannot wrap the `_container` partial in a cache block, since it contains dynamic content. I'm aware that I could key the cache block based on the dependent variables in the dynamic partial, but assume that the complexity of the dynamic partial is too high to cache.

What is a good way to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a gem to solve this problem:

https://github.com/neighborland/cache_rocket

Comment: You should run some benchmarks to check that this is actually giving you any benefit; I’m skeptical that it would help. There’s little to gain (and possibly something to lose) in caching purely static content, and I suspect the extra call to `sub` would hurt performance.

Comment: Good point. I'm getting a 15-20% improvement in rendering speed in early tests. It certainly depends on how much html you're able to cache.

Comment: Actually there is a huge amount to gain in caching static html content, which is why I'm doing this.

Comment: I can see how you could benefit from caching if you have a more complex set of nested partials, since than you’d be replacing several calls to `render` with a cache lookup. I guess this is what your real system is like? The example in the question is probably too simple to benefit, as the cached content (in `_container.html.haml`) doesn’t doesn’t use `render` at all, it’s just static content.